# Find out what is my most liked Facebook comment or post on Facebook or external site

Tags: facebook

I was told that some of my comments got lots of likes. However, I don’t remember it. So I want to find out which one is it and where. How can I do this?

Comment: by external site i mean that how i can leave facebook comments of external sites  and people like it there

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using Facebook desktop interface. Additionally, unless you know the URL it will be near impossible to find this in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I was told that some of my comments got lots of likes. However, I don’t remember it. So I want to find out which one is it and where. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much the only way you possibly could, is by going to your "activity log" and scrolling through all your posts/comments. Kind of annoying and time consuming. If you remember the date of the comment though that narrows it down a lot more. I wish they offered a feature for this!

Comment: hey thanks for answering the question, but what i really wanted to know comments i left on another website not on my posts. I don't think comments i leave on other websites actually show up in activity feed.